# Cannot get this property name using this code and expression api

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

I have the following class and I need to get its property names:

```
public class PMLButtonData
{
    public int BackgroundColorID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Callback
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

To get the names I'm using this function

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> lambda)
{
    MemberExpression member = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    PropertyInfo property = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

    return property.Name;
}
```

I can get the Callback property name using this code:

```
string name = GetPropertyName<PMLButtonData>(x => x.Callback);
```

But the same code for the other property doesn't work:

```
string name = GetPropertyName<PMLButtonData>(x => x.BackgroundColorID);
```

The only difference between them is the data type, so I changed the Callback to int and the code does not work with this property anymore. Why can't I get the name of a property this way if it's an integer?

Comment: that isn't reflection. thats the expression api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the type of your expression tree - you're trying to represent a delegate of type `Func<T, object>`, and if the property returns an `int`, that means it would need to be converted. You just need to make the method generic in both the source *and target* types:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<TSource, TTarget>
    (Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> lambda)
```

Now you should be able to do:

```
string name = GetPropertyName<PMLButtonData, int>(x => x.BackgroundColorID);
```

I realize that's slightly annoying, but you can trampoline via a generic *type* instead, so you only need to infer a single type parameter:

```
public static class PropertyName<TSource>
{
    public static string Get<TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> lambda)
    {           
        // Use casts instead of "as" to get more meaningful exceptions.
        var member = (MemberExpression) lambda.Body;
        var property = (PropertyInfo) member.Member;
       return property.Name;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
string name = PropertyName<PMLButtonData>.Get(x => x.BackgroundColorID);
```

Of course, in C# 6 you don't need any of this nonsense:

```
string name = nameof(PMLButtonData.BackgroundColorId);
```

:)

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing its boxing the `int` into `object` first. Try this signature:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T, T2>(Expression<Func<T, T2>> lambda)
```